# Is it a bad practice to create one DTO for many classes that implements an abstract one?

Tags: c#, dto

For example:

I have:

- a abstract class Animal with property Name
- Dog implements Animal and has property Country
- Cat implements Animal and has property Size

Can i use a DTO as follows?

```
AnimalDto {
    public string Name { get; set;} 
    public string Country { get; set;}
    public string Size { get; set;}
    public AnimalType Type { get; set}
}
```

Comment: You *could* but what type of logic is this going to create in your code? Are you planning on doing `AnimalType` checks before you use `Country` and `Size`?

Comment: I receive the DTO, and then send it to a factory which checks the type and create the correct Domain class.

Comment: You'll often find that this is classic death by OOP.  Eventually you'll have so many types and factories that any feature expansion may become a death crawl.  Do you gain enough code reuse to warrant this type of tight coupling?

Comment: The problem is that if I make a DTO for `Dog` and other for `Cat` I will need to cast the `Animal Dto` (abstract) to access to the `Dog Country` for example.

Comment: @mb2012 yeah, but what happens when you pass the animal to code which expected it to be a dog, but it’s actually a cat? You’re not solving the casting problem, you’re just forcing any and all other code to know what type of animal they’re dealing with... which means that code will have to type check (not cast). This approach ignores the benefit of the type system. It's the type of approach you'd need to take if you were using JavaScript and didn't trust the calling function. I spend a lot of my time figuring out how to avoid these problems, because it will will complicate future development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, you can have a look at the SOLID principles, more especially [the Single Responsibility Principle](https://web.archive.org/web/20150202200348/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf) which states that a class must have only **one** reason to change.

If your DTO regroups all the properties all of the classes belonging in the Animal kingdom, it will have to change every time one each of these classes need to change. It will change if Cat changes. It will change if Dog changes. And so on. I would avoid that.

As stated in other answers, it might worth to rethink the design, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public abstract AnimalDTO
{
    public static AnimalDTO Create(Animal animal)
    {
        var dog = animal as Dog;
        var cat = animal as Cat;
        if (dog != null)
        {
             return Dog(dog.Country);
        }
        else
        {
            return Cat(cat.Size);
        }
    }

    public static AnimalDTO Dog(string country) => 
        new Animals.Dog(country);

    public static AnimalDTO Cat(string size) =>
        new Animals.Cat(size);

    public abstract void Switch(Action<string> isDog, Action<string> isCat);

    private static class Animals
    {
        public class Dog : AnimalDTO
        {
            readonly string country;
            public Dog(string country)
            {
                this.country = country;
            }
            public override void Switch(Action<string> isDog, Action<string> isCat) => isDog(country);
    }
    public class Cat : AnimalDTO
        {
            readonly string size;
            public Dog(string size)
            {
                this.size = size;
            }
            public override void Switch(Action<string> isDog, Action<string> isCat) => isCat(size);
    }
}
```

For example:

```
public void CallFactory(Animal animal)
{
     var a = AnimalDTO.Create(animal);
    Factory(a);
}

public void Factory(AnimalDTO animal)
{
    animal.Switch(
        isDog: (country) => {
            // here you can be sure that the animal is dog
            // you can use country variable
            Console.Writeline($"It is a dog! from country {country}");
        },
        isCat: (size) => {
           // it is a cat
           Console.Writeline($"it is a cat of size {size}");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is an XY problem. Why use an abstract class at all?

There is *always* a way to avoid creating an abstract class - with the exception of having to subclass an abstract from a library you are consuming but have no control over. How? Use interfaces, and when you need common functionality, use static functions or use composition with another class.

I realize this isn’t a direct answer to your question, but it may solve your problem.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
}
```

From this, you end up with two classes, both of which you could use as a DTO, neither of which have unnecessary properties.

At runtime you can type check.

```
IAnimal myAnimal = ... ;

Helpers.DoSomethingWithAnimal(myAnimal);

switch (myAnimal)
{
    case (Cat cat):
        Helpers.DoSomethingWithCat(cat);
        break;

    case (Dog dog):
        Helpers.DoSomethingWithDog(dog);
        break;
}
```

When serializing, you could insert an extra property to keep track of what type of animal you need to deserialize the data back in to.

```
{
    name: "My Dog",
    country: "Romania",
    "__animal-type": "dog"
}
```